# NOT EXISTS is returning unexpected results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query to select approver credentials based on location, building number, etc. I want to have a default approver for a specific location, so an entry is made in the table with a Site value and NULL for Building and AcctDept. The result set is expected to be a single row.

Here is the query:

```
select distinct CS, Primary, Backup1, Backup2 
from Approvals 
where AcctDept = #ApprovalInformation.Account# 
            and Building = #ApprovalInformation.Building# 
            and Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
            and AcctDept is not null 
            and Building is not null 
union 
select distinct CS, Primary, Backup1, Backup2 
from Approvals 
where AcctDept = #ApprovalInformation.Account# 
            and Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
            and AcctDept is not null 
            and Building is null 

union select distinct CS, Primary, Backup1, Backup2 
from Approvals 
where Building = #ApprovalInformation.Building# 
            and Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
            and AcctDept is null 
            and Building is not null 

union 
select distinct CS, Primary, Backup1, Backup2 
from Approvals 
where Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
            and AcctDept is null 
            and Building is null 
and NOT EXISTS (
                    select * 
                    from Approvals 
                    where AcctDept = #ApprovalInformation.Account# 
                            and Building = #ApprovalInformation.Building# 
                            and Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
                            and AcctDept is not null 
                            and Building is not null)
```

My thought was that if the first SELECT returns a value, then the default is not needed, and the NOT EXISTS statement will evaluate false. (The first select is just copy/pasted into the NOT EXISTS of the last statement)

However, when I run this, it is always evaluating to TRUE.

There must be something about the behavior of NOT EXISTS that I am missing?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish.  `NOT EXISTS` is logically the same as a `NOT IN`.  You are trying to exclude records.  But these are records that you've already *included* in your first union.  Can you give some sample info to demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example. PL/SQL is exclusively used in **stored procedures** in Oracle.

Comment: @paqogomez To clarify, the user will provide Site, Building and AcctDept. In the case where the AcctDept and Building are not found (no match on the first SELECT), there is a table entry that has NULL for these values and the info for the default approver. I need to return only one row.

Comment: Why not simply do a check if you need to run the other parts instead of trying to union it all together with some more or less difficult to follow where logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 CS, Primary, Backup1, Backup2 
from Approvals 
where (AcctDept = #ApprovalInformation.Account# or AcctDept is null)
            and (Building = #ApprovalInformation.Building# or Building is null)
            and Site = #ApprovalInformation.Site# 
order by AcctDept, Building
```

default ordering in oracle is asc, nulls last. With the top 1 clause this will give you one record back with non-null AcctDept and Building if available. Untested as no SQLFiddle was provided.

Comment: This worked using `WHERE ROWNUM <= 1`  I don't think that I can condense my logic as you have done.